NET MAUI : Android native Layout with XML layout leads to Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException
When using MAUI handler to incorporate LinearLayout, an error is thrown : Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException
The XML used is the following and put in the Platforms\Android\Resources\layout (which doesn't exist by default in MAUI) and its build action set to AndroidResource.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, World!" />
</LinearLayout>`

The XAML is lie this :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp102.Pages.page10"
             xmlns:androidWidget="clr-namespace:Android.Widget;assembly=Mono.Android;targetPlatform=Android"
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             Title="page10">
    
        <ContentView HeightRequest="400" WidthRequest="400">
         
        </ContentView>
   
</ContentPage>

And the handler like that :
 Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization2", (handler, view) =>
#if ANDROID
        {
            handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Layout.myxml);
#endif
        });

When i click on a button that open my Content Page the following error appear : Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException
{Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Drawable com.companyname.mauiapp102:layout/layout2 with resource ID #0x7f0b0032
 ---> Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: File res/layout/layout2.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0b0032
 ---> Android.Views.InflateException: Class not found LinearLayout
 ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "LinearLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~.../com.companyname.mauiapp102-Sg4xnqr_Su3KqEezYw0ZLg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~fuxDokti2OmCHcE6YFiRuA==/com.companyname.mauiapp102-Sg4xnqr_Su3KqEezYw0ZLg==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~fuxDokti2OmCHcE6YFiRuA==/com.companyname.mauiapp102-Sg4xnqr_Su3KqEezYw0ZLg==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]

I have search for hours but i can't find any solution.
Any Ideas ? Many thanks !!

Did you register the handler in MauiProgran.cs file?

Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I will try to reproduce your problem based on your code.
